# Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is not allowed access with Gulp, Restangular, Java EE and Wildfly 8

Tags: javascript, java, gulp, wildfly, restangular

The Restangular works fine with post() or get(), but if I want to delete something, then I got the following error:

> *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed
>   access.*

I tried the solution on this site:

[How to enable Cross domain requests on JAX-RS web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450494/how-to-enable-cross-domain-requests-on-jax-rs-web-services)

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                       final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {

        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }

}
```

But then I got the following error:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8888, *', but only one is allowed. Origin
>   'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.

I don't quite understand what does this error mean and how could I fix it? Thanks!

The localhost:8888 is defined in Gulp.

Comment: If you get CORS error, it should be for all of your request methods, unless DELETE goes somewhere different ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added these codes in our web.xml and it solves the problem:

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header must just be 'http://localhost:8888'

It is explained well in the second answer in the thread:
[Why is jquery's .ajax() method not sending my session cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie)