# Jax-RS not registering resource with @provider annotation

Tags: java, rest, jersey, weblogic, jax-rs

I have a rest application running in weblogic 12c using jersey api. I have a http request filter class with an annotation @provider. however when deploying the application the filter class is not registered with the other resource classes that I have added in my ApplicationConfig class. and subsequently I am not able to filter the http requests. below are my logs and the code

```
Sep 01, 2015 11:16:12 AM weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer onStartup
INFO: Number of JAX-RS specific classes to be examined:24
Sep 01, 2015 11:16:12 AM weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.BaseServletContainerInitializer addServletWithApplication
INFO: Registering the Jersey servlet application, named com.ws.rest.ApplicationConfig, at the servlet mapping, /rest/*, with the Application class of the same name
Sep 01, 2015 11:16:12 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18.1 02/19/2014 03:28 AM'
Sep 01, 2015 11:16:12 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig$ApplicationHolder <init>
INFO: Instantiated the Application class com.ws.rest.ApplicationConfig
Sep 01, 2015 11:16:14 AM weblogic.jaxrs.onwls.deploy.ejb.provider.EJBComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding the EJB class com.ws.rest.UserController to EJBManagedComponentProvider
Sep 01, 2015 11:16:14 AM weblogic.jaxrs.onwls.deploy.ejb.provider.EJBComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding the EJB class com.ws.rest.ReportsController to EJBManagedComponentProvider
Sep 01, 2015 11:16:14 AM weblogic.jaxrs.onwls.deploy.ejb.provider.EJBComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding the EJB class com.ws.rest.MainController to EJBManagedComponentProvider
Sep 01, 2015 11:16:14 AM weblogic.jaxrs.onwls.deploy.ejb.provider.EJBComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding the EJB class com.ws.rest.BusinessController to EJBManagedComponentProvider
Sep 01, 2015 11:16:14 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void com.ws.rest.BusinessController.resetCalls(), MUST return a non-void type.
<Sep 1, 2015 11:16:14 AM EAT> <Warning> <com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors> <BEA-000000> <The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void com.ws.rest.BusinessController.resetCalls(), MUST return a non-void type.> 
<Sep 1, 2015 11:16:14 AM EAT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The server has successfully established a connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service.> 
<Sep 1, 2015 11:16:14 AM EAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN.> 
<Sep 1, 2015 11:16:14 AM EAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>
```

here is the applicationconfig class

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")

public class ApplicationConfig extends Application{

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    s.add(MainController.class);
    s.add(UserController.class);
    s.add(ReqFilter.class);
    s.add(BusinessController.class);
    s.add(ReportsController.class);
    return s;
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    MOXyJsonProvider moxyJsonProvider = new MOXyJsonProvider();

    //moxyJsonProvider.setAttributePrefix("@");
    moxyJsonProvider.setFormattedOutput(true);
    moxyJsonProvider.setIncludeRoot(false);
    moxyJsonProvider.setMarshalEmptyCollections(true);

    HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(1);
    set.add(moxyJsonProvider);
    return set;
}
  }
```

request filter class

```
@Provider
public class ReqFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReqFilter.class);

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws WebApplicationException {
    logger.info(requestContext.getMethod());
}


 }
```

the log file shows nothing is written when I call my urls. how does one register such a class?

Comment: Have you tried to register it as a singleton? As an aside, with Jersey it is more common to extend `ResourceConfig` rather than `Application`. From my experience extends `ResourceConfig` just works better, on top of being easier to configure the application

Comment: Are you using web.xml? Have you tried com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter instead of javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter

Comment: Actually another thing I just noticed. The server seems to be using Jersey 1.x. You can tell by the `com.sun.jersey...` log messages. Jersey 2.x would be `org.glassfish.jersey...`.

Comment: You're going to need to get rid of anything jersey 2.x/jax-rs 2.0 related so you aren't confused in what to use. After doing that, your filter will not compile, as it is a Jax-rs 2.0 class. Jersey 1.x does have a filter with the same name, just the package is different and the contract is a bit different

Comment: I ended up deploying a shared library for jax-rs 2.0 and jersey 2.19 from this link https://github.com/georgeyanev/weblogic-jax-rs. now the filter is registered but now the other classes are not being registered and I get nullpointer exceptions when i try to call those resources. however this is only happening to those urls that are calling the EJBs. the urls that dont require data from db are returning responses quite perfectly. what could have affected my ejb bindings?

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 approaches. The one you described must work, however, try to put the Filter first in the list of classes.

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    s.add(ReqFilter.class);
    s.add(MainController.class);
    s.add(UserController.class);
    s.add(BusinessController.class);
    s.add(ReportsController.class);
    return s;
}
```

The second approach is to use `@Provider`. But if you do so, you need to extend the `Application` class and **leave it empty!**

Checkout [this blog entry for a complete example](https://vvirlan.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/jax-rs-use-provider-to-leverage-jax-rs-provider-auto-discovery-feature/)

Answer (score 1):

I deployed a shared library [weblogic-jax-rs](https://github.com/georgeyanev/weblogic-jax-rs)
 and then referenced it in my weblogic.xml

```
<library-ref>
  <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
  <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
</library-ref>
```

and the filters got registered. however this messed up all my java EE annotations and all urls getting data from EJB invocations are broken.

Comment: Have you found a solution to avoid problem with the URLs?