# How to load REST resources in Angular-Seed bootstrap project from a JEE7 back-end

Tags: angularjs, rest, jakarta-ee, angular-ui-router, wildfly

I am trying to learn hot to invoke a RESTful service that I've implemented in JEE7. I am using the bootstrap template [Angular-Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) and the file structure in the tutorial I am using looks a bit different. What I can't seam to figure out is how the `$routeProvider` and controller relate to each other.

The file structure I have look like this and is similar to the current Angular-Seed structure.

```
app/                    
    bower_components/  
    components/           
    view1/                
            view1.html          
            view1.js            
            view1_test.js       
    view2/                
            view2.html          
            view2.js            
            view2_test.js
    app.css 
    app.js
    controller.js
    service.js
    index.html            
    index-async.html
```

Include the service and the controller in the `index.html`.

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="services.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

Added reference to the `mainCtrl` in `app.js`

```
    'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',  
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
            when('/view1', {
                templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            })
}]);
```

In the `services.js` file I've declared the invocation of the RESTful service.

```
var tweetObsService = angular.module('tweetObsService', ['ngResource']);

tweetObsService.factory('tweetFactory', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/bongo-obs/rest/tweets/findAll', {}, {
        query: {
            method:'GET',
            params: {},
            isArray:true}
    });
});
```

In the root file `controller.js` I've declared the mainCtrl.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, tweetFactory) {
  $scope.tweets = {};  
  tweetFactory.query().$promise.then(function(tweets) {
    $scope.tweets = tweets;
  });
});
```

The JSON that the service retrieves has the following structure.

```
[
  {
    "id": {
      "timestamp": 1454579718,
      "machineIdentifier": 12550416,
      "processIdentifier": 6912,
      "counter": 6510561,
      "time": 1454579718000,
      "date": 1454579718000,
      "timeSecond": 1454579718
    },
    "userId": 0,
    "status": null,
    "user": {
      "id": 291655833,
      "name": "Anders Anderson",
      "screenName": "Superuser",
      "location": "Sweden",
       ...
```

Lats but not least, I tried to render result from the REST service in the  `view1/view1.html`.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="tweet in tweets">
        <td>{{tweet.user.screenName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've no alter the project thanks to submitted answer but I get an error related to the `$injector`

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tweetFactoryProvider <- tweetFactory <- mainCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/unpr?p0=tweetFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20tweetFactory%20%3C-%20mainCtrl
    at http://localhost:8383/mobile-clear-obs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8383/mobile-clear-obs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4346:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4494:39)
    at http://localhost:8383/mobile-clear-obs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4351:45
    at getService (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4494:39)
    at invoke (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4526:13)
    at Object.instantiate (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4543:27)
    at http://localhost:8383/mobile-clear-obs/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9395:28
    at link (app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:977:26)
    at invokeLinkFn (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9039:9) (09:47:06:656 | error)
```

How do I correctly injection my mainCtrl, so I can use it in `view1.html`?

**EDIT:** Alter the question in response to the submitted.
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947040/niklas).

**FINAL EDIT** I finally got there with help from [niklas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947040/niklas). The last  problem I stumbled upon is cross domain referencing, resulting in `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` If your backend is running on another server (still localhost), you have to allow cross domain calls to your back-end. Read this [post how to solve this problem in JAX-RS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450494/how-to-enable-cross-domain-requests-on-jax-rs-web-services).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app.js`

```
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',  
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version',
  'tweetObsService'
]).
config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
            when('/view1', {
                templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            })
}]);
```

The `controllers.js`

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('YourView1Controller', function($scope, tweetFactory) {
  $scope.tweets = {};

  tweetFactory.query().$promise.then(function(tweets) {
    $scope.tweets = tweets;
  }
}
```

For the view you can then access your desired data like 
`{{tweets.user.screenName}}`and so on

To access the tweetFactory you have to declare the module `tweetObsService`. with the rest of the modules in `myApp`.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',  
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version',
  'tweetObsService' //add this line
]). ...
```

Make sure your services.js is included in your index.html (some starter projects do it automatically...)

Comment: Didn't have time during the weekend to try your solution. Updated the question according to you answer. But it seams that I am missing reference to my controller somehow?

Comment: Thanks @niklas for the help on my first AngularJS test.