# How to enable CORS with JAX RS API 1.1

Tags: cors, resteasy, jboss6.x

I'm using JBoss 6.4 EAP with Resteasy 2.3.10 Final and jaxrs api spec 1.1 (all of these libraries are already provided within the container).

I miss ContainerResponseFilter because it's contained into jaxrs 2.0 spec, therefore this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23631475/3042207) doesn't work in my case. 
Which method could I use to enable CORS ?

Answer (score 3):

I had to implement standard javax.servlet.Filter in this way:

```
package javax.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns="/*")
public class ApiOriginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, api_key, Authorization");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

Comment: This was the only working solution to my problem too. I used Resteasy 2.3.10 Final just as you did.

Comment: Thanks, this solution help me with Resteasy 2.3.7 Final and JBoss 6.2 EAP