# Wildfly allow OPTIONS Methods but return 405 Method not allowed

Tags: javascript, soap, xmlhttprequest, cors, wildfly

I'm trying to send xml with `POST` method in javascript using the `XmlHttpRequest` object. 
On my server I've a web service which receives SOAP request.

When I want to send xml, the browser previusly try to send a preflight `OPTIONS` request to the server, but it returns `OPTIONS 405 Method Not Allowed`.

The problem is that I've in my response header the `Access-Control-Method-Allowed : POST,OPTIONS,GET,PUT` so I guess  my server accepts OPTIONS method, but my web service only understands `POST` request.

Here's some code :

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open('POST', url, false);
 var sr = mySoapRequest; //Here's my XML 

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =  () => {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {                           
             var xml = xmlhttp.responseXML;
             console.log(xml);
             this.showAlert(xml);
         }
     }
 }
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "file/xml");
 xmlhttp.send(sr);
```

Here's my HTTP protocol request headers :

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:192.168.149.127
Origin:http://192.168.149.1:8100
Referer:http://192.168.149.1:8100/?ionicplatform=android
```

Here's my HTTP protocol response headers :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:224
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 16 Feb 2017 10:25:33 GMT
Server:WildFly/8
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
X-XSS-Protection:1
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

> The problem is that I've in my response header the Access-Control-Method-Allowed : POST,OPTIONS,GET,PUT so I guess my server accepts OPTIONS method

No.

That just means that when you respond to whatever request you are putting that header in, you are *telling the browser* that it is acceptable to make cross-origin OPTIONS requests.

That does absolutely nothing to make your server respond to an OPTIONS request with `200 OK` instead of `405 Method Not Allowed`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28996470/19068) suggests:

```
@OPTIONS
@Path("{path : .*}")
public Response options() {
    return Response.ok("")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Indeed, you're right. As I can't have an access to the web-service code, I'll develop an other solution with a middleware service which does not use xmlhttprequest :) thanks for your answer