# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jax-rs

How to debug this problem ?

This is my java code. I give permission for all ip by setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but still it says no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

```
   return Response.ok().entity(jsonNodeToSend.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
```

This is my javascript code.

```
var dict = {
"clientMac" : "48:43:7c:53:53:d1",
"BSSID" : ""
};

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://104.155.189.170:8080/Localization/rest/clientMacPosition/get/7',
crossDomain: true,
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
data: dict,
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('MessageId', 'abc123');
},
success: function(responseData, textStatus, messageId) {
    console.log("success");
},
error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(responseData);
    console.log(errorThrown);
}
```

});

Here is my method which gets the data and respond to the request.

```
@Path("/get/{customerProjectId}")
@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response gettingRecentPosition(LocationAPIReceiverDTO locationAPIReceiverDTO,
                                      @PathParam("customerProjectId") int customerProjectId) {

     JsonNode jsonNodeToSend = null;


    return Response.ok().entity(jsonNodeToSend.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();


}
```

URL: http://104.155.189.170:8080/Localization/rest/clientMacPosition/get/7

jsonData : {
    "clientMac" : "48:43:7c:53:53:d1",
    "BSSID" : "33:"
}

My REST call response in POST man.

[image]

Comment: Imho setting only the header is not enough. You need code that handles the preflight request that is specified here: https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ . In node i use a package for that. I'm sure in JAVA is a similar solution. Perhaps: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html ?

Comment: Did you able to hit your API with postman

Comment: @AjitSoman yes I can do that, but it does not work in ajax.

Comment: @AjitSoman It does work in PostMan.

Comment: Could you provide URL , Header  and data that you are sending

Comment: @AjitSoman I have provided the needed data.

Comment: Did you able to get data with this : `$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url:'http://104.155.189.170:8080/Localization/rest/clientMacPosition/get/7',
contentType: "application/json;",
data: { "clientMac" : "48:43:7c:53:53:d1", "BSSID" : "33:" },
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
},
error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}`

Comment: @AjitSoman I have added this, but still the same problem. You can try in jsfiddle or in your local.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151505/discussion-between-vidhya-sagar-and-ajit-soman).

Comment: Did you tried all solutions available at this url:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450494/how-to-enable-cross-domain-requests-on-jax-rs-web-services

Comment: @AjitSoman I have tried all solutions. I even added FilterHolder to the embedded jetty server, but still, i have the same problem. Still at office. GET works, only POST doesnt works.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: Please try this :  $.post("http://104.155.189.170:8080/Localization/rest/clientMac‌​Position/get/7",
    { "clientMac" : "48:43:7c:53:53:d1", "BSSID" : "33:" },
    function(data, status){
        console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a filter for your application and add the following header to fix CORS issue:

public class ApplicationFilter implements Filter {

```
 @Override
 public void destroy() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
 throws IOException, ServletException {

     HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
     HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
     httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", httpRequest.getHeader("Origin"));
     httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
     httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE,PUT");
     httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
     httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,Authorization, Content-Type,*");
     if (httpRequest.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
         httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
         return;
     }
     chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
 }


 @Override
 public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put `@CrossOrigin` annotation on your controller method?

Here is an example of how to set up cross origin with spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: I am not using any spring. I have just deployed jar file with the internal jetty server in vm. Added the javax.ws.rs.* framework. Everything working perfectly for GET method, not for POST.

Comment: ok, can you post controller class? Or at least the whole method declaration where you are responding to a request

Comment: I have done it. Please take a look. Do i need to add some other annotation? I have no controller class. I have only REST class.

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450494/how-to-enable-cross-domain-requests-on-jax-rs-web-services