# unable to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, java, cors, access-control, preflight

I need to access my web api hosted remotely from my react app. On the server side i did below to allow cross domain communication:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.mypackage.ResponseDto;

@Override
public Response fetch(String id, String env) throws ServiceException
{ 
     ResponseDto res = new ResponseDto();
     res = updateResp(id, env); // not important

     return Response.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*").entity(res).build();
}
```

When i check from postman i can see cors header correctly set as below:

```
access-control-allow-origin →*
content-type →application/json
date →Wed, 16 Aug 2017 11:07:16 GMT
server →web
transfer-encoding →chunked
```

But when i access the same endpoint from react app, browsers starts complaining with below error:

> Fetch API cannot load
>   http://myservices.com/myservice-app/services/. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

Any idea whats going on here?

Edit#1
Did below change still see the same error:

```
return Response.ok()
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With")
            .entity(response).build();
```

Comment: The header needs to be added to the response to an OPTIONS request(which is what a browser will send as this 'preflight' request), not (just) GET or POST. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: How does the response of the server look like when it receives a OPTIONS request, this is send before the next request

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: @all please see latest edit #1

Comment: I don't think the edit would really help, if you are still just setting those headers on non-OPTIONS requests. It's not obvious from the code you posted where `fetch` is being called from. Have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450494/how-to-enable-cross-domain-requests-on-jax-rs-web-services) answer for some useful info on enabling CORS in your environment.

Comment: Are you certain it’s not just that your browser has a stale copy that was cached before you added the response headers? Try clearing your browser cache, and check the Network tab in your browser devtools to see whether the browser is loading it from its cache

Comment: As far a checking with postman, you need to test by sending an OPTIONS request, because your browser is doing a CORS preflight OPTIONS before making the actual request you want to send. You also need to make sure you’re sending an `Origin` request header when you test, and that you’re sending the `Content-Type: application/json` request header. I don’t know the details on how to do those with postman, but using curl, it looks like this: `curl -X OPTIONS -i -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://myservices.com/myservice-app/services/`

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with whatever Java library you're using, but something like this must work:

```
@Override
public Response options() throws ServiceException
{ 
     ResponseDto res = new ResponseDto();

     return Response.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*").entity(res).build();
}
```

**If the library works like I think it does**, this will send a `200 OK` on every `OPTIONS` request you send to your server, with header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *`. That's what you should be aiming for.

Comment: This works only if the api does not involve any custom headers(like origin, content-type, accept, authorization), for api calls with some custom headers this wont work